# JPA Criteria Object comparisons can only use the equal() or notEqual() operators

Tags: java, sql, jpa, join

Lets say i have following code:

```
@Embeddable
Class Xyz { // has only one field
    private String value;
}

@Entity
Class B {
    @Embedded
    private Xyz xyz;
}

@Entity
Class C {
    private B b;
}
```

Now in my `CDao` method - `getAllByXyz(List<String> values)` I would like to get all C entries from db where `c.b.xyz.value` is in `values`. Here is what i got:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<C> q = cb.createQuery(C.class);

Root<C> r = q.from(C.class);
q.select(r);

Join<C, B> join = r.join(C_.b);
Expression<String> e = r.get(B_.xyz);

Predicate p = e.in(values);

q.where(p);
return em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

The error says `Object comparisons can only use the equal() or notEqual() operators.` As far as I understood there is problem connected with `Xyz` class and `value` field. How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QueryException: Object comparisons can only use the equal() or notEqual() operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719104/queryexception-object-comparisons-can-only-use-the-equal-or-notequal-operat)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose It is not a duplicate. I don't know how to refer to Xyz value field. i can't write r=get("xyz.value");